# RegEx to start with the last occurance of the string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text file with a data set I want to remove some records from. It looks like this:

> 1. =separator=
> 2. data
> 3. **unwantedKeyword**
> 4. data
> 5. =separator=
> 6. data
> 7. wantedKeyword
> 8. data
> 9. =separator=
> 10. data
> 11. **unwantedKeyword**
> 12. data
> 13. =separator=
> 14. data
> 15. wantedKeyword
> 16. data
> 17. =separator=

I can use a certain keyword to identify records I don't want (or want). I wanted to use RegEx utilizing this keyword and a separator string to remove all those expressions.
Removing the "bottom" part of the record works fine, but when I try to remove the "top" bit using this:

> =separator=.*?unwantedKeyword

the start of the match is on the 1st available =separator= (line 5.) rather than the last one (line 9.) before the end keyword (line 11.) resulting in wanted records being removed.

Is it possible to match only the last instance of that string (=separator= in the mock data) so only lines 1. to 3. and 9. to 10. rather than 1. to 3. and 5. to 11. would be replaced?

EDIT:

Or I guess just make it read the file in backward direction? Notepad++ disables that option for RegEx tho, so not sure if that's possible either.

Comment: Why is separator first and unwanted keyword second, and not vice versa?

Comment: That just gets rid of the "bottom" part of the record, so in this case lines 3 to 5 and 11 to 13 leaving lines 2 and 10 untouched. Which works fine and is a 2nd part of what I need to do, but not all of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove line 1 to 3 and line 9 to 11, you can use a lookahead to prevent matching all the lines that either start with `=separator=` or contain unwantedKeyword.

```
^=separator=.*(?:\R(?!(?:=separator=|.*?\bunwantedKeyword\b)).*)*\R.*?\bunwantedKeyword\b.*\R*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LoZ2oB/1)

[image]

Comment: "If you want to remove line 1 to 3 and line 5 to 11"


I guess I wasn't clear. I want to remove likes 1 to 3 and 9 to 11. The main issue is that lines from 5 to 11 are removed instead.

Comment: @M.Bugajski Ah, I made a typo. It does remove lines 1 to 3 and lines 9 to 11

Answer (score 1):

I'd use

```
(?s)=separator=(?:(?!=separator=).)*?unwantedKeyword
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/blLxkJ/1/).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?s)                     set flags for this block (with . matching \n) 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  =separator=              '=separator='
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      =separator=              '=separator='
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .                        any character
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*?                      end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  unwantedKeyword          'unwantedKeyword'
```